# Trying to convert UNIX Epoch time into Normal date from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert unix epoch time into normal date from JSON.

JSON code (not full):

```
{"success":true,"lastUpdated":1621365664405
```

I have this code:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

r = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar').json()

#last updated datetime
time = r['lastUpdated']
datetime_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(datetime_time)
```

But I get the following error: **Line 9, in 
datetime_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'). OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument**

Comment: Please debug and locate the line which produces the error.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: What does `r['lastUpdated']` actually look like?

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp returned is in miliseconds, while what you need is a timestamp in seconds. Just divide "time" by 1000 and it should do the trick, I think.
Hope it helped!

**EDIT:**
Also, you don't need to use strftime. The following should also work:

```
# Import the whole datetime module
import datetime as dt

time = r['lastUpdated'] / 1000
# Use the date module, instead of the datetime module
datetime_time = str(dt.date.fromtimestamp(time))
```

This will give back your string in the format you desire. Use whichever you prefer.

The code as you want it can be:

```
time = r['lastUpdated'] / 1000
```

Just with that line changed, it should work.
Hope it helped!

Comment: Your welcome! As advice, always check the type of the object being returned, because the error could have been coming from the timestamp being returned as a string, as someone else pointed out. And that python timestamps work in seconds, so if the timestamp returned is in miliseconds or even nanoseconds, you'll have to convert it. I always use the following website to check: https://www.epochconverter.com/